# SQL Dinamico, ¿Saber si la DB Existe SQL 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Planteo mi problema. Tengo un Servidor de Base de datos SQL Server 2008 en el cual constantemente se están creando nuevas bases, muchas de ellas tambien las van borrando y no tengo conocimiento completo de como trabajan el log de registros, porque efectivamente puedo ver cuales bases se han eliminado, pero hace un tiempo dejó de mostrar muchas, entonces pienso que el LOG lo borran o lo mueven.

Me gustaría un SQL Dinamico en donde yo indique por alguna variable o cursor, todas las bases que deseo consultar si existen y que por cada una devuelva el valor "existe" o "no Existe".

No tengo nada avanzado ya que no se me ocurre el cómo podría hacerlo. Pensé con algún cursor junto con un while, pero no se me ocurre en verdad.

¿Alguna idea de como podría?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ejecutar esto:

```
declare @NombreBd varchar(50)
declare db cursor for
SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases
open db
fetch next from db into @NombreBd
begin
    print @NombreBd
    fetch next from db into @NombreBd
    --Select o cualquier consulta con Exec(...)
end
deallocate db
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar una tabla temporal para tener los nombres de las bases de datos y a partir de esto hacer una consulta que te regrese lo que necesitas,

```
    CREATE TABLE #Tabla
    ( nombreDB    VARCHAR(30))

    SELECT 
         nombreDB,
        CASE 
            WHEN   name IS null  THEN 'NO Existe'
        ELSE   
           'Existe'
         END    AS  Estatus
   FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases    DB
   RIGHT JOIN   #Tabla             T
   ON   DB.name                     =               T.nombreDB
```

con esto puedes hacer un SP o un script acorde a lo que necesitas.

Espero te sirva.